# phpbb url writing issue (design get disturbed)

Tags: php, phpbb, phpbb3

I am doing url rewriting in phpbb my url is working fine but when I am writing url rewrite like http://server.com/forum/topic then my pages design get disturbed.

when I get view source I am getting url like "./styles/prosilver/template/..."

How can I change it to "http://server.com/styles/prosilver/template/..."

If any one know hoe to set and in which file please tell me.

Thanks.

Comment: Thats how phpBB writes URLs as default, there is no need to change it to write absolute paths.